# How to access PHP files using HTTP over peer-to-peer network?

Tags: php, http, networking, p2p

I connected two PCs (say PC1 and PC2) using a patch cable (Category 5E) while both of them run on Windows 7. The IP addresses for PC1 and PC2 are 192.168.1.2 and 192.168.1.3, respectively. I've successfully configured a homegroup for the two computers and there was no problem in simple file sharings.

What I should know is that, having installed WAMPServer and stored some PHP files in PC1's root directory, how could I access them from PC2? I tried typing 'http://192.168.1.2/aphpfile.php' in the PC2's browser. And, I got no expected result. The browser simply said that it could not access the page. I'm not an expert in networking. Please help me.

PS: Please, **don't** close this question as a duplication. I searched related questions in this site but nothing was found helpful to me.

Comment: Can you ping the second server?

Comment: You don't need PHP to share files, Apache is enough.

Comment: @powtac -> Yep! I pinged it and I found no possible errors! And, please note that  I just wanted to access my PHP page stored in PC1 using the PC2! Not as file sharing but as if it were accessed from the internet.

Comment: @Cherone -> If that was a firewall problem, how can I rectify it? Can you please explain that for me?

Comment: did you select "online" when you left click on WampServer's icon seems silly, but i think WampServer edits the apache.conf file to restrict to localhost only unless you set it "online"

Comment: if you can ping the server then its not a firewall problem...

Comment: @Cherone -> Yes, indeed. I don't get any errors while pinging. But more confusingly, while I diagnosed the problem in IE, I got the error message that goes like this: "website (192.168.1.2) is online but isn't responding to connection". Please, don't doubt me. I'm sure I got 0% loss when I pinged it!

Comment: Thanks for suggesting "Put online" attempt. But, it was unsuccessful. I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

By default, WAMP assumes you're developing locally and will not answer requests made from outside the machine. You have to click ["put online"](http://www.infinitedesigns.org/archives/217) from the WAMP menu. It will configure Apache to start listening for incoming connections from outside your machine.

Comment: & Cherone -> Thanks for suggesting "Put online" attempt. But, it was unsuccessful. I get the same error.